# Why is Date("2014-04-07") parsed to Sat Apr 05 2014 17:26:15 GMT-0500 (CEST)?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm creating dates like this:

```
var StartDate = new Date(data.feed.entry[i].gd$when[j].startTime);
```

When a date string is received specifying date and time in the form:

```
"2014-04-12T20:00:00.000-05:00"
```

`Date()`  interprets this perfectly fine returning:

```
Sat Apr 12 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
```

However, when the date string is received with no time information in the form:

```
"2014-04-07"
```

then `Date()` is interpreting it as:

```
Sat Apr 05 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
```

Looks like `Date()` is taking the -07 as the time and I have no clue where is it getting the date as 05. Any idea what might be the problem?
Could it be, somehow, `Date()` is interpreting  a different time zone because in the first string the time zone is determined at the very end but in the "all day" event there is no indication of the time zone.

Has anybody found this issue? If yes, how did you solve it?

UPDATE: After researching a little bit more this parsing issue I noticed something very weird:

The following statement:

```
 new Date("2014-4-07")
```

would return Mon Apr 07 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT) which is correct, but the following one:

```
  new Date("2014-04-07")
```

returns Sun Apr 06 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT) which is the wrong one. So, for whatever reason, seems like the padding zeros affect the way the date is parsed!

Comment: You sure `"2014-04-07"` Gives back `Apr 05` and not `Apr 06`?

Comment: Tip: Simplify your question, e.g. `Date("2014-04-07")` is parsed to `Sat Apr 05 2014 17:26:15 GMT+0200 (CEST)`. Anybody found this issue? - I never had this problem, interesting. How about you check the length and just append `"T00:00:00+0000"` to the end?

Comment: Yes, the values I'm posting here are copy-pasted from the console. I think this is because of the lack of time-zone difference in the returned string because, mathematically, it matches the results but I don't know how to tell, dynamizally, if the string is coming with time-zone included or not.

Comment: @ZeissS Thanks for the recommendation on the re-phrasing of the question I think is more clear as you put it. I could append the string as you are suggesting. (I probably need to do something like "T00:00:00-0500") but that would be hard since I'd need to know when the daytime savings would change and such. I was hopping Google's API and Date() have a way to handle this automatically.

Comment: @Thelemitian I checked and cannot reproduce your problem. `new Date("2014-04-07")` gives me the correct Date in my local timezone. Maybe this is your problem, as your timezone value is much larger than mine.

Comment: @ZeissS: I'll dig deeper and try to get to the bottom of this. Thanks a lot for trying it! (:

Comment: @ZeissS: Notice the big difference between `new Date("2014-04-07")` and `Date("2014-04-07")`!

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, I noticed that. But his code shows `new Date()` so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Interesting... this might be a n00b thing but didn't know there is a difference bewteen new Date() and Date(), I mean I thought one was just a function while the otherone would create a variable. In my code I'm using  New Date( Google's Info);

Comment: @Thelemitian: I cut away a bunch of the cruft in your question. Please verify that it represents your issue. The top half seemed entirely irrelevant. Roll it back if it isn't right.

Comment: Is it possible that you were previously using `Date()` without `new`, and the script is cached by the browser? If so, try clearing the cache or changing the name of the script to reload it.

Comment: @cookiemonster: Yes it looks good. I think my question was either: to understand why a string in the form "YYYY-MM-DD" is not interpreted correctly or how to make Google API return a "all day" event as a "YYYY-mm-DDTHH:mm:ss.000-05:00" string but I guess understanding what Date is doing is more important. Thanks for the edits! (:

Comment: @ZeissS, I don't know if you saw my recent update but new Date() seems to parse a date differently when the month and the day have leading zeros or not. One will include the time zone, the other won't.

Comment: @Thelemitian Now I saw it. Actually, I think `Date` is right here. The `[...]19:00:00-0500 (CDT)` is the correct one, as it is midnight UTC. You may want to append the `T00:00:00-05:00` part with your local timezone, to end up with a correct date in your local time.

Comment: @ZeissS I think I will need to look into the solution you propose. I just need to find a way to automatically determine when the Daylight Savings time starts because for half of the year I have to append a -05:00, for the other half -06:00.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `Date()` function wrong.

It only accepts parameters in the following formats.

```
//No parameters
var today = new Date();

//Date and time, no time-zone
var birthday = new Date("December 17, 1995 03:24:00");

//Date and time, no time-zone
var birthday = new Date("1995-12-17T03:24:00");

//Only date as integer values
var birthday = new Date(1995,11,17);

//Date and time as integer values, no time-zone
var birthday = new Date(1995,11,17,3,24,0);
```

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Example%3a_Several_ways_to_assign_dates).

The `Date()` function does not accept timezone as a parameter. The reason why you think the time-zone parameter works is because its showing the same time-zone that you entered, but that's because you're in the same time-zone.

The reason why you get `Sat Apr 05 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)` as your output for Date("2014-04-07" ) is simply because you used it in a different way.

`new Date(parameters)` **will give the output according to the parameters passed in it.**

`Date(parameters)` **will give the output as the current date and time no matter what parameter you pass in it.**

Comment: MDN is not authoritative, it is a community wiki that anyone can register and a member and create or edit entries. Use ECMA-262. There you will find that the only string format that is specified is a version of ISO 8601 and it does not include a timezone, only Z (and assumes Z if no timezone is supplied). Otherwise, parsing of date strings is entirely implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to ES5, parsing of date strings was entirely implementation dependent. ES5 specifies [a version of ISO 8601](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2) that is supported by may browsers, but not all. The specified format only supports the Z timezone (UTC) and assumes UTC if the timezone is missing. Support where the timezone is missing is inconsistent, some implementations will treat the string as UTC and some as local.

To be certain, you should parse the string yourself, e.g.

```
/* Parse an ISO string with or without an offset
**   e.g. '2014-04-02T20:00:00-0600'
**        '2014-04-02T20:00:00Z'
**
** Allows decimal seconds if supplied
**   e.g. '2014-04-02T20:00:00.123-0600'
**
** If no offset is supplied (or it's Z), treat as UTC (per ECMA-262)
**
** If date only, e.g. '2014-04-02', treat as UTC date (per ECMA-262)
*/
function parseISOString(s) {
  var t = s.split(/\D+/g);
  var hasOffset = /\d{2}[-+]\d{4}$/.test(s);

  // Whether decimal seconds are present changes the offset field and ms value
  var hasDecimalSeconds = /T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+/i.test(s);
  var offset = hasDecimalSeconds? t[7] : t[6];
  var ms = hasDecimalSeconds? t[6] : 0;
  var offMin, offSign, min;

  // If there's an offset, apply it to minutes to get a UTC time value
  if (hasOffset) {
    offMin = 60 * offset / 100 + offset % 100;
    offSign = /-\d{4}$/.test(s)? -1 : 1;
  }
  min = hasOffset? +t[4] - offMin * offSign : (t[4] || 0);

  // Return a date object based on UTC values
  return new Date(Date.UTC(t[0], --t[1], t[2], t[3]||0, min, t[5]||0, ms));
}
```

An ISO 8601 date string should be treated as UTC (per ECMA-262), so if you are UTC-0500, then:

```
new Date('2014-04-07'); // 2014-04-06T19:00:00-0500
```

The behaviour described in the OP shows the host is not compliant with ECMA-262. Further encouragement to parse the string yourself. If you want the date to be treated as local, then:

```
// Expect string in ISO 8601 format
// Offset is ignored, Date is created as local time
function parseLocalISODate(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D+/g);
  return new Date(s[0], --s[1], s[2],0,0,0,0);
}
```

In your function you can do something like:

```
var ds = data.feed.entry[i].gd$when[j].startTime;
var startDate = ds.length == 10? parseLocalISODate(ds) : parseISOString(ds);
```

Also note that variables starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors, hence *startDate*, not *StartDate*.

Comment: Your `parseLocalISODate` doesn't *parse* a date?

Answer (score 0):

(I would add a comment but i don't have 50 rep yet)

See what

new Date().getTimezoneOffset()

returns, I would expect a big negative value, that would be the only reasonable explanation to your problem.

I have had some trouble with date conversions in the past, in particular with daytime saving timezones, and as work around i always set the time explicitly to midday (12:00am). Since I think you were using knockout,  you could just make a computed observable that appends a "T20:00:00.000-05:00" or the appropiate time zone to all "day only" dates

Comment: You mean like a 29-hour-offset? That would be odd indeed.